# TensorFlow LSTM to classify MNIST - understanding changing number of timesteps

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, mnist

**Context**

I am trying to understand RNNs, both implementation (in TensorFlow) and theory. As part of this I've written a simple LSTM using TensorFlow to classify MNIST handwritten digits.

For this I use TensorFlow's `dynamic_rnn`, with an input shape of `[batch_size, max_timesteps, number_of_inputs]` (and `time_major=False`).

When I feed the MNIST image into the model with 28 timesteps, and 28 pixels input at each timestep (for 784 total pixels), the model works well, training fast and achieving high accuracy (~1 min/epoch, 98% accuracy with 128 hidden units).

However, if I feed the image into the model pixel-by-pixel, so that there are 784 timesteps each with input size 1, the model performs extremely poorly (~30 mins/epoch, max accuracy of 40%).

**Questions**:

- What exactly is going on here? Why does feeding the images in pixel-by-pixel cause the model to perform so poorly? Is it to do with there not being enough context or there being too many timesteps or must there be something wrong with the model?
- Is there any way to change this so that the model will work well when fed the images pixel-by-pixel? I have heard of truncating the backpropagation at a certain number of timesteps, but the TensorFlow docs are unclear on how exactly to do that and I haven't found any decent guides yet.

**Code, If It's Helpful:**

```
# ================ IMPORTS ================

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import numpy as np

# =========================================

# ================ CONFIG VARIABLES ================

# Have tried learning rates 1, 0.5, 0.01, 0.005, 0.0001, 0.00001 as well, this one
# was best so far
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
BATCH_SIZE = 50
NUM_EPOCHS = 20

# Setting input and steps to these values is fast and accurate
#NUM_INPUT = 28
#NUM_STEPS = 28

# Setting input and steps to these is very slow and inaccurate
NUM_INPUT = 1
NUM_STEPS = 784

# Number of hidden layer features in the LSTM
NUM_HIDDEN = 128
FC_LAYER_UNITS = 100

# Number of classes to classify into
NUM_CLASSES = 10

# Defines how often the network's accuracy is printed to show the user
DISPLAY_EVERY = 50

# Early stopping threshold. The early stopping mechanism works by saving the model every time its accuracy on the test
# set is higher than any previous accuracies. If more than this number of steps have passed since the model was last
# improved, the model is deemed to be unable to achieve a higher accuracy and training is stopped.
MAX_STEPS_SINCE_SAVE = 10

# ==================================================

# ================ FUNCTIONS ================

def binarize(images, threshold=0.1):
    """
    Changes MNIST images into binary versions of themselves, where each pixel is either a 1 or a 0
    :param images: the images as flat 1D arrays to turn into
    :param threshold: the required value for each value to be classified as a 1
    :return: the binarized image
    """
    return (threshold < images).astype("float32")

def weight_variable(shape):
    """
    A function to create TensorFlow weight variables.
    :param shape: the dimensions of the variable to be created
    :return: a TensorFlow weight variable ready for training
    """
    variable = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(variable)

def bias_variable(shape):
    """
    A function to create a TensorFlow bias variable.
    :param shape: the dimensions of the variable to be created
    :return: a TensorFlow bias variable ready for training
    """
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

# ===========================================

# ================ MAIN ================

# ==== Graph Definition ====

# Read the MNIST data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_Data", one_hot=True)

# Input to the LSTM
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, NUM_STEPS, NUM_INPUT])
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, NUM_CLASSES])
seqlens = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

# Define the LSTM cell, dropout wrapper and the dynamic rnn
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(NUM_HIDDEN, forget_bias=1.0)
lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell=lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, inputs, dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=seqlens)

# Get the final output
outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])
last_rnn_output = tf.gather(outputs, int(outputs.get_shape()[0]) - 1)

# Define a weight and bias variable
W = weight_variable([NUM_HIDDEN, FC_LAYER_UNITS])
b = bias_variable([FC_LAYER_UNITS])

# Linear layer for LSTM output
lstm_out = tf.matmul(last_rnn_output, W) + b

# Add a ReLU layer
activations = tf.nn.relu(lstm_out)

# Add a final affine transformation
W2 = weight_variable([FC_LAYER_UNITS, NUM_CLASSES])
b2 = bias_variable([NUM_CLASSES])
pred = tf.matmul(activations, W2) + b2

# Now we need a loss function and optimizer
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=labels))
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE).minimize(loss)

# Model evaluation
correct_predictions = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, tf.float32))

# A global variable initializer
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# ==== Training ====

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Keeps track of the number of steps since the model last achieved a winning accuracy. If this is greater than a
    # threshold, then the model is deemed to have achieved the highest possible accuracy and training is stopped.
    steps_since_save = 0

    # Keeps track of the highest accuracy yet achieved by the model.
    highest_accuracy = 0

    # Initialise variables
    sess.run(init)

    # Calculate how many batches we have
    total_batches = int(mnist.train.num_examples / BATCH_SIZE)

    for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):

        for batch in range(total_batches):

            # Get a batch of data
            batch_data, batch_labels = mnist.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)
            batch_data = binarize(batch_data)

            # Reshape the training data into a NUM_STEPS x NUM_INPUT image rather than a flat array
            batch_data = batch_data.reshape((BATCH_SIZE, NUM_STEPS, NUM_INPUT))

            seq_lens = [NUM_STEPS] * BATCH_SIZE

            # Run optimization
            sess.run(opt, feed_dict={inputs: batch_data, labels: batch_labels, seqlens: seq_lens, keep_prob: 0.5})

            if batch % DISPLAY_EVERY == 0:

                num_test = 1000

                # Test images
                test_data = binarize(mnist.test.images[0:num_test])

                # Reshape test images
                test_data = test_data.reshape((-1, NUM_STEPS, NUM_INPUT))

                seq_lens = [NUM_STEPS] * num_test

                # Run accuracy and loss
                test_acc, test_loss = sess.run([accuracy, loss], feed_dict={inputs: test_data, labels: mnist.test.labels[0:num_test], seqlens: seq_lens, keep_prob: 1})

                # Display the information
                print("\n\t\t-->> EPOCH ", epoch, ", BATCH ", batch, "  <<--\n")
                print("--> Number of Hidden Units: ", NUM_HIDDEN)
                print("Accuracy: ", test_acc, ", Loss: ", test_loss)

                # Update the highest accuracy and save if we beat the previous highest accuracy.
                if test_acc > highest_accuracy:
                    print(">> New Highest Accuracy, Saving Model <<")
                    #saver.save(sess, SAVE_PATH)
                    print(">> Model Saved <<")
                    highest_accuracy = test_acc
                    steps_since_save = 0
                else:
                    steps_since_save += 1

        # Model has fully trained, stop training
        if steps_since_save > MAX_STEPS_SINCE_SAVE:
            print("\n\n**** MODEL CONVERGED, STOPPING EARLY ****")
            break

# ======================================
```

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but feeding 28 pixels at a time (row by row) is very different from feeding one pixel at a time, to an RNN. Say you have a dependency from the first pixel of the first row to the first pixel of the second row. In the second cast, the RNN must remember something 28 positions ago. RNNs (depending on the activation function) have an exponential decay in memory and can't remember much after more than 10 steps.

Comment: @drpng Shouldn't LSTM solve the problem of remembering?

Comment: The word on the street is that LSTMs can't remember beyond 7 positions or so.